# String comparison

Tags: java, string

I want to compare two strings and return true if the second string is present in the first string.

```
   @Test
   public bool compareStrings{
        String text1="hello world";
        String text2="hello but some xyz world and xzy bla bla";
        /* I want to check if text2 contains text1 */
   }
```

Comment: And did you try `text2.contains(text1)`?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-string-contains-example/)

Comment: downvoted, the method name is painfully obvious and even if you didn't think of that you could always look at the api. Programming is mostly debugging so I suggest you learn how.

Comment: i tried many , i wanted a solution where the if(text2.contains(text1)){ system.out.println("text2 contains text 1 ")}     the whole point is , if your observe text2 it contains text1 but not in sequence , i wanted a small program which could check for text without any sequence

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:-

```
text2.toLowerCase().contains(text1.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: this just converts to lowercase , so i dont think its gonna change

Comment: I have used toLowerCase() just to ignore the case sensitivity. If you want you can use it without using that function. But I am afraid that why it is not working for you...I am sure you are missing something because as per your question it will definitely work..

Comment: i tried many , i wanted a solution where the if(text2.contains(text1)){ system.out.println("text2 contains text 1 ")} the whole point is , if your observe text2 it contains text1 but not in sequence , i wanted a small program which could check for text without any sequence

Answer (score 1):

You want to do:

```
if (text2.indexOf(text1) > -1)
{
  // text2 contains text1
}
```

Comment: i tried many , i wanted a solution where the if(text2.contains(text1)){ system.out.println("text2 contains text 1 ")} the whole point is , if your observe text2 it contains text1 but not in sequence , i wanted a small program which could check for text without any sequence , also i want to use  Assert.assertTrue(text2.contains(text1))